# Update an entire row in Excel using OleDB command

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I am trying to blankout/clear an entire excel tab. But nothing seems to work

I tried the following approach:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
OleDbCommand count = new OleDbCommand("Select count(*) FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);

DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
adapter.Fill(dataset);

for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow dtRow = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i];
    foreach (DataColumn col in dataset.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        if(col.DataType == typeof(string))
        dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][col] = "";
   }

}
dataset.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
adapter.Update(dataset.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: The question should be "Update an entire table in Excel using OleDB command"

Comment: What's in your worksheet? OleDb will not get rid of formatting and any cells that contain formulae are effectively read-only.

Answer (score 1):

If your Excel file has primary key,you can use OleDbCommandBuilder,if not, OleDbDataAdapter or OleDbCommand will be a better way.adapter.you can't directly use Update(dataset.Tables[0]),here is the code:

```
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", myConnection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            string updateSQL = string.Format(@"UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET Status =? WHERE ID IN ( SELECT TOP 5 ID FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Status <>? OR Status IS NULL )");
            adapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(updateSQL, myConnection);
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = "Status";
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@OldStatus", OleDbType.Char, 255, "Status").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
            dt.AsEnumerable().Take(5).ToList().ForEach(o => o.SetField("Status", @"Imported"));
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            adapter.Update(dt);
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess to manipulate excel file, [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) is a better option for you.

It's open source & easy to use.

I used OLEDB to read excel file before, but never try to use it updating data. If you have to use it, make sure your excel file is not readony.

Comment: Constraints to use third party :(